# How can I synchronise web projects at home and work?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am currently developing 10 websites for my job. I use codeIgniter PHP framework for each one.

I develop both at home (localhost) and work (localhost) and upload changes to the server.

My current workflow is as follows:
Work (HTDOCS) <-> USB Stick <-> Home (HTDOCS)

I do not really have one "central" location for the files, I just try to keep the latest copy on all mediums at all times. I have been looking at source version control (completely new to me).

I am considering learning GIT and keeping the repository on my USB stick, checking out at home and work to alter files and excluding the 3 config files?

1) codeIgniter has three files that are unique to either home, work or server. config.php has the app directory, database.php has the local database settings, and .htaccess alters the base url to remove index.php and this varies between machines.

2) Can I use source version control like git to keep the files on my USB stick as the central location? If so, how do I do it with 10 different websites? And for my photoshop files as well?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoes a few weeks ago and I use [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) now for my projects.  I found Bitbucket after I did a search for `free repository` and ran across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories).

Answer (score 0):

> I am considering learning GIT and keeping the repository on my USB stick, checking out at home and work to alter files and excluding the 3 config files?

You can use Git this way:

- Store bare-repo on stick
- Add mentioned location-specific files to .gitignore
- Have two "binded" to location repositories (WORK & HOME)
- Sync repos using push|pull

> how do I do it with 10 different websites?

One site - one separate repository